# I need to find the average of a set of test scores, but need to drop the lowest

Tags: textpad

I am programming fundamentals right now, and have an assignment that asks for the average of assignment grades. I have to drop the lowest grade, but am not sure how to do that part. The most recent thing we've learned so far is a "do loop", but I just don't know how to actually drop the lowest grade while getting the average of the highest 4.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow and programming in general. First of all, you shouls specify the language you are programming with. Secondly, you should first try on your own (especially if you are a beginner). If you don't succeed then post your code attempt and we will aid where we can

Comment: Language he/she is using is irrelevant. If you have five grades and you want to drop the lowest one, just ignore the lowest grade and with the four remaining, add them up and divide by four to find the average.